# Trying to ask user for rows,columns,depth to make a 3 dimensional board not working?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing this code so that I can make a connect 5 game(same as connect 4 but with a twist). We have to ask the user for the board size then store that into a 3 dimensional array. This is what i have so far but when i print out the rows, column, and depth it's always 0? can anyone tell me how to fix?

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Connect5 {
int maxSize = 10;
int size = 0;
int rows = 0;
int cols = 0;
int depth = 0;
int x,y,z = 0;
int board[][][];

public void makeBoard(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter number of rows : ");
        try
        {
            rows = scan.nextInt();
            if (rows <= 10 && rows >=5)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Number of rows should be between five and ten!");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter number of columns :");
            cols = scan.nextInt();
            if (cols <= 10 && cols >=5)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Number of columns should be between five and ten!");

            }
            System.out.println("Enter depth :");
            depth = scan.nextInt();
            if (depth <= 10 && depth >=5)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Depth should be between five and ten!");

            }

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
    board = new int [rows][cols][depth];
    String result="";
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        result=result+"Data Array "+x+":";
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
            {
                System.out.println("Rows: "+x+"\nColumn: "+y+"\nDepth: "+z+"");
                board[x][y][z] = scan.nextInt();
                result=result+board[x][y][z]+", ";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    Connect5 board = new Connect5();
    board.makeBoard();
    System.out.print(board);
}
}
```

Comment: Is your problem the array *dimensions* or the array *contents*?

Comment: after compiling the code you have posted above, I find it working using row=9, column=9 and depth = 9

Comment: Did you write this piece of code that you have posted?

Comment: Yes I wrote this code why?

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the minimum size of rows,columns and depths to 2 and run it. Results were as expected.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Connect5 {
int maxSize = 10;
int size = 0;
int rows = 0;
int cols = 0;
int depth = 0;
int x,y,z = 0;
int board[][][];

public void makeBoard(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter number of rows : ");
        try
        {
            rows = scan.nextInt();
            if (rows <= 10 && rows >=2)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Number of rows should be between five and ten!");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter number of columns :");
            cols = scan.nextInt();
            if (cols <= 10 && cols >=2)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Number of columns should be between five and ten!");

            }
            System.out.println("Enter depth :");
            depth = scan.nextInt();
            if (depth <= 10 && depth >=2)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Depth should be between five and ten!");

            }

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
    board = new int [rows][cols][depth];
    String result="";
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        result=result+"Data Array "+x+":";
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
            {
                System.out.println("Rows: "+x+"\nColumn: "+y+"\nDepth: "+z+"");
                board[x][y][z] = scan.nextInt();
                result=result+board[x][y][z]+", ";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

public void print(){
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        //result=result+"Data Array "+x+":";
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
            {
                System.out.println(board[x][y][z]+" ");
                //board[x][y][z] = scan.nextInt();
                //result=result+board[x][y][z]+", ";
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    Connect5 board = new Connect5();
    board.makeBoard();
    board.print();
}
}
```

Comment: its a connect 5 game so the minimum has to be 5 or no one can win and it is no longer a connect 5 game.

Comment: I also tried the code you've added here and i dont get the results i need. it still says rows,columns, and depth are all 0.

Comment: Are you talking about dimensions or the values itself?

Comment: The dimensions have to been a minimum of 5x5x5 or a max of 10x10x10. Therefore the user has to input a number between 5 and 10 for rows, columns, and depth.